# How to Pass Additional Parameter to handleProviderCallback function inside Login Controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I get my previous url in `redirectToProvider` function, and now I want to pass it to the `handleProviderCallback` function so that I proceed further.

How can I achieve that?

Here is my route:

```
Route::get('auth/{provider}', 'Auth\LoginController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('auth/{provider}/callback', 'Auth\LoginController@handleProviderCallback');
```

And here is my Login Controller function:

```
public function redirectToProvider($provider)
{
    //$url = url()->previous();
    return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
{
    //`How can i get the $url here`
    $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();

    $domain = explode("@", $user->email)[1];
    if( $domain != 'abc.edu.pk')
    {
        return redirect($this->redirectTo1);
    }
    else
    {
        $authUser=$this->findOrCreateUser($user, $provider);
        Auth::login($authUser, true);
        return redirect($this->redirectTo);
        //return $user->token;
    }
}
```

Comment: save it to the session

Comment: But How brother???

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/session#using-the-session  enjoy